# search for line from data base with time complex of O(1) \ O(log n)

Tags: c++, c

I am creating .txt file that contains a lot of lines with different length.

**edit:** I need to build some kind of data base, doesn't have to be .txt file
the first stage is building the database - O(n)

the data base need to contain (line_number, line_content)

on the second stage- my goal is to search for a specific line in O(1) or O(log n). and after finding that line, return every line after that in O(1) and process it.

```
search line() -> O(1) or O(log n) 

while (!End_Of_Lines)
  {
    bring next line() -> 0(1)
    process_line()
  }
```

is there a way to return a pointer to specific line in O(1) or O(log n) instead of O(n)?

if the .txt file is not very good idea, is there other way to maintain such lines structure?

thanks.

Comment: I believe binary search is probably the way to go (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Is the file sorted somehow?

Comment: reframe the qs with code example that you tried

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask yourself a question: *what is a line in a text file* in c++?

The answer is: *it is a sequence of characters that ends with a `\n` or `\r\n`*.

Therefore, in order to tell how many lines there are, you need to scan the entire file and while doing that, possibly store line start/end positions.

Your question is very vague so I'm assuming you want to read the file and start the search immediately. If that's the case, it is not possible to find a line without scanning the entire file (or part of the file up to your line).

But if you mean read the file, parse it and the search for a line, then it is possible to reduce the search time using different search algorithms. But then you're not searching the file but some other structure, really.

**EDIT:**

To go further on your edit, assuming that specific line means specific line number, you need to first parse the file, for every `eol` found you have to store the lines in a container, probably `std::vector <std::string>`. If then you want to process all lines starting from line `x`, then you do (assuming `vec` is your container):

```
if (x < vec.size()) //incrementing iterator past vec.end() will result in a segfault
{
    for (std::vector <std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin() + x; it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        process_line(*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: you right, my question wan't so clear. I edited my question,  I need to build such data base, it doesnt have to be .txt file.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how many lines supposed to be, it is not constant value. and vector will copy the entire previous array to a new one and I think it a bit wasteful...

Comment: @user3378689 I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I thought maybe to use map.- the search is O(log n) but the next line_number will be also O(log n) and I need it to be O(1)

Comment: @user3378689 Why do you want to use map? What sort of keys do you want to use? If it's integers (line numbers) then you're most certainly better off with vectors. Have you read about vectors, random access complexity is O(1)

Comment: o.k thanks! can I treat vectors as same as array? I have been thinking and I need that every cell will be a struct: pointer to data and size of data. is it possible?

Comment: @user3378689 Um, why? `std::string` encapsulates all that. Please, study some basics first... And make use of standard library facilities if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you need to do repeatedly on the same input file, then you could build an index of where each line starts, and use that index to find each line.

Since lines are not "known" to the filesystem, C++ `std::stream` etc, in any other way than "a lump of text in a file that is delimited by a newline", there is no easy way to determine where the next line starts from the beginning of a given line. So one way or another, you will have to READ the file up to the point of line N to know where line N starts.